# How to configure a CacheStoreProvider in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, .net, caching, distributed-caching, .net-4.7

In .NET 4.7, they have introduced a feature to [plug any cache store as the default object cache implementation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cachestoreprovider(v=vs.110).aspx). However, I can't find any documentation from Microsoft, any help or even a blog on how to configure any cache store other than `MemoryCache` as the default object cache.

Please direct me to any link that helps me understand it's configuration.